# Industrial strength cryptography

Tags: javascript, encryption

The length of time it takes any loop iteration to complete is always peculiar. The idea here is that if you tie up JS's single thread with lots of loops the (actually random) length of time it takes to get through them, it can never repeat.

Please explain how it fails.

```
let i = 0;

function dropDaMic() {
    console.log('\nTa-da! These numbers are unique and patternless.\n');
}

function getBusy() {
  console.log ('\nPlease wait: doing busy stuff...\n');
          let     arr      = [],
                  i        = 1999999999,
                  start    = new Date().getTime(),
                  stop;
          do {
            i--;
            arr.push[i];
          } while (i);

          stop  = new Date().getTime();
          realRandom(start, stop);
}

function realRandom(start, stop) {
    let amIpunked  = start / stop;
    console.log ('Unique number' + ' #' + i + ' : ' + amIpunked);
}

function startMeUp(count) {
    i++;
    !!i <= count ? (getBusy(), startMeUp(count - 1)) : dropDaMic();
}

startMeUp(3);
```

Comment: It's still not clear what question you're asking. You said your code works. What do you problem do you want help with? @donkeyotey. Someone in your duplicate questions suggested codereview.stackoverflow.com - did you take them up on that?

Comment: @Andy Yes! :-) I did. And guess what happened: nothing. Mr know-it-all is a trigger happy chap.

Comment: @Andy I did sculpture in college. I'm very bad at maths. I'm ok at simple JS, but I don't know how to approach proving it, so I want one or some of the brilliant minds who help out on SO to explain why it isn't working, because from my dim view it is bulletproof.

Comment: What do you mean by "Please explain how it fails"? In what way is it not working? Also, even without knowing exactly what you're trying to do here, I can tell you this method will not produce cryptographically random numbers.

Comment: Also, you use a lot of terms/phrases in your question that don't make sense. "every iteration in every function to complete is always unique" <-- How is it "unique"? "the difference between the first time and the second time can never repeat" <-- Why not? "an infinite system" <-- What do you mean by an infinite system? "the randomness creeps left " <--- What do you mean? "computers round-up from the right-hand side" <--- This isn't clear.

Comment: This coding style is hard to read, and the whole presentation ("explanatory" text, variable names, etc.) makes me not want to look at this, to be frank. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: "I don't have room to explain" You don't have room to explain your question? If you include a lot of unclear terms/phrases in your question, people won't understand what you're asking. If you want an answer, it's probably in your best interest to simplify your question or clarify what you mean.

Comment: @Cully I mean that your questions: "How is it "unique"?,  "Why not?" and "What do you mean?" can't be answered in 500 characters. AND they are all already answered by me on my site. Is that fair?

Comment: What I'm saying is that your question isn't clear. You should update it to either remove unnecessary content (especially terms you seem to have your own definition for) or clarify it. Basically distill the question down to its most basic form and be as clear as possible. Otherwise you'll just keep getting people asking what you mean or what you want rather than getting a helpful answer. Also, asking people to "look at my website" is definitely not going to help you get an answer.

Comment: Also, just FYI, your question isn't difficult to understand because it's going over peoples' heads. It's difficult to understand because of the way you've chosen to ask it. The idea of trying to generate random numbers using the time to process something isn't new. It's a naive approach that people often think of when they don't understand how randomness works and it's been proven not to work. So the idea isn't complicated. Your question is just confusing.

Comment: @Cully I'm just doing my best to respond to you (and everyone) in as concise a manner as I can. The questions you asked ARE too complicated to answer here and they are answered on my site. If you ask questions and are too intimidated to visit a URL to see the answer, I don't think I can help you :-(

Comment: I'm just trying to help you get an answer to your question. it sounds like you've tried a few times and gotten a similar response. It's because of the way you've asked it. If you simplify the question and get rid of terms that don't really mean anything, you'll be more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of statistical tests that can be applied to a generator to get some idea of its statistical randomness. I think it's probably worth approaching some of your claims directly instead. The obvious answer to "how does this not work?!" is of course, "prove that it DOES work". The proof you've offered up is very weak.

> the time it takes every iteration in every function to complete is always unique. So if you give a single thread a lot to do, and time how long it takes, you cannot get the same number.

This just isn't a founded claim. Two different functions or calls to the same function can take the same amount of time. If I time how long water takes to boil, it may well come up with the same value twice.

> So, the difference between the first time and the second time can never repeat, because an infinite system (like this one) everything happens only once.

This is the same claim with more fluff on it. "Infinite systems" can absolutely repeat. Consider the number sequence of an infinite number of `1`s.

Also "not-repeating" is not the same as "random". Consider the sequence of natural numbers. There's no repetition, but it's certainly not cryptographically secure randomness.

> The reason the randomness creeps left is that numbers are infinite, but computers round-up from the right-hand side. The people I want to read this already know that - numbers are not trimmed, they are rounded.

I really don't know what this means, sorry.

Your RNG is vulnerable to some common pitfalls also. The results can be manipulated by resource allocation on the host machine (thus increasing/decreasing runtime).

Most JS interpreters will perform optimizations over time as code runs. This system would likely need to be at least "warmed up" before being in a state that's even consistent.

Comment: Thank you. Now can you please direct me somewhere I can access some of these statistical tests? In an infinite system, everything happens only once. Everybody knows this, but some of us need reminding. :-) All of that is explained on my site (deafInOneEye[.]com). Also, there is only one infinite system and you're sitting in it and to be more reasonable, it's not a system because systems thoery is neccessarily nonsensical because it depends on time, which simply doesn't exist in exactly the way Santa doesn't. :-)

Comment: I'd like to explain my understanding of what's happening to the generated numbers, but I really am very bad at maths, so I'm afraid I can't explain my (mis)understanding of what's happening - that's more or less why I posted the question.

Comment: There are tons of great results just googling "how to test an rng" Here's one at random https://www.cs.rice.edu/~johnmc/comp528/lecture-notes/Lecture22.pdf . It sounds like you're working with some unclear definitions of "system" et cetra. They're not relevant here, because we're talking about javascript, not the entire universe, but you should update your question to (once again) include all the information needed for someone with no context.

Comment: When I try to point out your misunderstandings, you say things like "we all know I'm right ;)" so I don't really see this being a productive use of my time going. best of luck, I hope what I've written here can help you to formalize your stuff a bit more.

Comment: Uniqueness != relevance. Every grain of sand is unique, but for the purposes of day-to-day activities, they're all identical if they're within a reasonable proximity of eachother. Sure, each instance of the number 1 is unique, but if my RNG only gives back `1`s, then in the real world, using it as a source of crypto security will get you "pwnd", because there is no practical consequence to the 1's being distinct. So maybe it's not bs but it is just irrelevant wordplay in the realm of real-life existant physical silicon-based computers and formal logic.

Comment: Well... here's the thing: as far as I know the function takes 2 timestamps and divides the smaller by the larger AND the interval simply cannot ever be the same length. Like I said: I did sculpture in college, but my lack of mathematics doesn't suddenly make the length of time it takes a loop to iterate regular.

Comment: "the function takes 2 timestamps and divides the smaller by the larger AND the interval simply cannot ever be the same length"  Let's say you run your algorithm, and for the purpose of simplicity, it starts at 1000 and ends at 2000. Your `amIpunked` value is `1000 / 2000`, which is `0.5`. Then you run it again and it starts at 4000 and ends at 8000. Your `amIpunked` value is `4000 / 8000`, which is `0.5`. That's the same value twice.

Comment: Cully, if that happens, it will only happen once, so why does it matter? The number is still unique. Also, a timestamp is never that even, it's theoretically possible, but it's never going to happen. :-). Also, as you may know (and I mentioned above) the length of time it takes a loop to iterate is always peculiar. 2 billion iterations of a loop take 2 billion different lenghts of time to execute. See what I mean?

Comment: One thing you should keep in mind: CPUs run on a very precise clock. They are essentially deterministic. The time it takes to do something like add two numbers together will always be exactly the same (as far as the CPU is concerned). Also, `Date.now()` gives you a timestamp in milliseconds. In terms of how quickly a CPU can perform operations, a millisecond is really no time at all. A 4GHz CPU can perform 4,000,000,000 operations per second, or 4,000,000 operations for millisecond. It's entirely conceivable that your start and stop times will be exactly the same or 1 or a few ms different.

Comment: "See what I mean?" I know exactly what you mean and what you're trying to do. I'm just trying to tell you that you're incorrect in your assumptions.

Comment: You're confusing uniqueness with randomness. And even if you're just trying to get a unique number, this algorithm is not good at producing unique numbers.

Comment: Cully, I am certain you are (much) better at coding and maths than I am, but this works by overloading JS's single thread. This wouldn't work in a multi-threaded language. And as for clocks: even atomic clocks get a different answer every time they try to measure a second - don't take my word for it: check it out. :-)

Comment: That's not how CPU clocks work. It doesn't matter how long it takes to generate a clock pulse, all the CPU knows is that one clock pulse has passed and it will move from one state to another. Any operation will take a specific number of clock pulses. That's "time" as far as a CPU is concerned, and it's deterministic.

Comment: Hey, Cully. You know what? I give up. Try running the code (watch out, it's slow) or don't. Someone already closed the question. I love stackoverflow, but right now it's not loving me back. Nobody who understands that adding random increments to any number creates a random number will ever see it. :-(

Comment: I re-wrote your algorithm and ran it a number of times. I can assure you it doesn't produce random values. It barely produces unique values. It's not random because the value is predictable. You should spend more time reading about randomness and the idea of entropy in randomness.

Comment: I get the impression that you have a good intuition for most things, you can probably pick up concepts quickly, and you have a high confidence in your ability to do so. There are many pitfalls in engaging with a subject in that way. But one of them is that it's hard for you to realize you don't actually understand something. You're so confident that you get it, and that others don't, that even when someone who has a deeper understanding of a subject tries to explain to you why you're wrong, you don't believe them.

Comment: Cully, You said it! :-): "It barely produces unique values." It does actually work. It's not a proposal for enterprise software, I'm just trying to explain the mechanism and as you just noticed, it does actually work.

Comment: You said you wanted to produce random numbers. This algorithm does not produce random numbers. Again, you're confusing random with unique.

Comment: Cully, I apologise for my ignorance. But it does produce unique numbers. Every time it runs. The fact that you wrote a script that does something different to this one doesn't change that. :-)

Comment: Please take this to chat and stop sending me notifications on this answer :)

Comment: @CollinD, when I click "automatically move this discussion to chat?" all that happens is the page scrolls up. Am I doing something silly, or is it because the question is closed?